# MongoDB - store strategy

Tags: mongodb

Coming from relational databases like your help on how to model my data. What is the best efficient way?

I'm working on a very simple microservice to manage organizations.
each organization has one field: `name` and list of users id's included in that organizations.

I can see two ways of modeling that data:

**1. separate documents:**

*organizations collection:*

```
{
   id: '88c4e67a-c4ba-11e9-aa8c-2a2ae2dbcce4',
   name: 'some organization'
}
```

*users collection:*

```
{ 
   userId: '7e27ff68-c4ba-11e9-aa8c-2a2ae2dbcce4', 
   organizationId: '88c4e67a-c4ba-11e9-aa8c-2a2ae2dbcce4'
}
```

**2. or as nested documents:**

*organizations collection:*

```
{
   id: '88c4e67a-c4ba-11e9-aa8c-2a2ae2dbcce4',
   name: 'some organization,
   users: [
      '7e27ff68-c4ba-11e9-aa8c-2a2ae2dbcce4',
   ]
}
```

from your experience, what the pros & cons of each strategy? what your preferred way? anything to consider in each strategy? is there is another better way to model this data in mongodb?

EDIT:
The types of queries I'll need is to:

1. fetch all organizations data (no necessarily need for the users id's)
2. fetch organization data (including it's users) by organization id
3. fetch organization by user id.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The best way to decide how to model your data is to ask yourself how you will be querying the data. Once you know what type of questions you'll be asking you will be able to store the data in a logical way.

Comment: @Lix very important point. you right. I'll edit the question with this insight

Comment: For example, you might be querying for a list of users in an organisation - for that, subdocuments sound appropriate. You might want to search for an org by a user - for that, it might not be the best idea to have users nested in orgs...

Comment: @Lix I'll actually need both: query by user id, and query by organization id.

Answer (score 1):

Given the high-level use case, I would prefer the de-normalized model (nested) which is the advantage you've in mongoDB and we must utilize it to get more out of mongo. The 'option 2' that you've mentioned is not nested document, you're just maintaining the field as array

In nested model, the data will look like:

```
{
   id: '88c4e67a-c4ba-11e9-aa8c-2a2ae2dbcce4',
   name: 'some organization,
   users: {
      user1: 'abc',
      user2: 'def',
      user3: 'xyz',
   }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm happy with the nested users: { ... } model. seems hard to maintain, as I don't need the `user1`, `user2`, `user3` keys. it doesn't represents anything. what the benefit of this store strategy?

Comment: The advantage you have is, you maintain all the related data within one single collection. In this way, you can avoid joins (fetching data from multiple collections). Remember, Joins have impact on query performance. Before modelling, there are many other factors to be considered, like is your app read or write intensive, number of TPS expected, access patterns, reterival patterns and so on. But in simple, a good data model, must always try to keep related data together